# SoundCloud API Embedding list of songs

Tags: javascript, embed, soundcloud

I'm trying to make a application where you can select a genre and BPM (beats per minute) and it will load in a embedded playlist from SoundCloud. And I'm stuck.

```
function playSomeSound(bpm, genre) {
    SC.get('/tracks', {
        genres: genre,
        bpm: {
            from: bpm
        }
    }, function(tracks) {
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49);
        SC.oEmbed(tracks[random].uri, {auto_play: false}, document.getElementById('target'));
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: '5805346946bfb91c8b6efb6023cae463'
    });
};

$('#generate').on('click', function(){
    var genreSelect = document.getElementById("sel1");
    var genre = genreSelect.options[genreSelect.selectedIndex].text;

    var bpmSelect = document.getElementById("sel2");
    var bpm = bpmSelect.options[bpmSelect.selectedIndex].text;

    console.log(bpm);
    console.log(genre);

    playSomeSound(bpm, genre);
});
```

I keep getting the error:

> GET http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=70&bpm[from]=dubstep&client_id=5805346946bfb91c8b6efb6023cae463&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200 400 (Bad Request)

And:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '33' of null

I suppose the second error is about the random number but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Figured it out, had my select 1 on BPM and 2 on Genre. I was selecting them the other way around.

Comment: Nice idea, but in my experience I find content creators rarely fill in the genre or bpm fields of tracks (which is a huge shame and I wish soundcloud enforced proper use of metadata). Be aware of that before sinking too much time in your app!